# Can you help me understand this Swift method?

Tags: swift, closures

I am building an app using Swift for the first time and using the [AlamoFire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire) library. I've built apps using Obj-C and AFNetworking before, but I'm having a hard time groking this Swift response method:

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://someapi.com/thing.json")
         .responseJSON { _, _, JSON, _ in
             println(JSON)
         }
```

The actual method definition is:

```
public func responseJSON(options: NSJSONReadingOptions = .AllowFragments, completionHandler: (NSURLRequest, NSHTTPURLResponse?, AnyObject?, NSError?) -> Void) -> Self {
        return response(serializer: Request.JSONResponseSerializer(options: options), completionHandler: { request, response, JSON, error in
            completionHandler(request, response, JSON, error)
        })
    }
```

I don't really understand what's going on here when I use this response method.

*Why am I not using parens in the method call?*

*Am I just passing a block or anonymous function into this method?*

*What is the significance of passing underscores (`_`)?*

*What is the `in` keyword doing?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's all here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH11-ID102

No parens: that's trailing closure syntax. Idea is that closures can get long, hard to remember/determine long-distance paren pair.

Yes, block = anonymous function = (anonymous) closure. Yes, you're passing that as the only parameter. Since it's omitted, 'options' gets its default value of '.AllowFragments'. Trailing closure `{ ... }` gets bound to `completionHandler` parameter.

The '_' is the 'don't care about this parameter' syntax ... e.g. if the function doesn't use the parameter, no point to giving it a local name.

`in` is part of closure syntax: indicates start of function body. Definitely read the whole closure syntax chapter above. It's designed to be extremely terse, nothing intuitive about it.